# How to get outlook email conversation using messageId in canvas app?

Tags: outlook, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am creating a canvas app that runs in ms teams, in that app I need to show emails both sent items and received emails of a specific conversation, currently I'm using Office365Outlook.GetEmail() function by passing messageId but this returns me a specific email only not the conversation, how do I get the whole conversation using messageId?

```
office365Outlook.GetEmail(First(Filter(Tickets, TicketId = ticketId)).EmailId).Body
```